# In org-mode why does org-latex-create-formula-image-program gives extra information?

Tags: preview, org-mode

In my .emacs I have  `(setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'imagemagick)`

It's working so I get a preview of the formula with `c-c c-x c-l`  but I also get an unwanted information `linktoc = all, colorlinks = true, urlcolor = DodgerBlue4, citecolor = PaleGreen1, linkcolor = black`

This is the content of
`\hypersetup{linktoc = all, colorlinks = true, urlcolor = DodgerBlue4, citecolor = PaleGreen1, linkcolor = black}` in a tex file in `\temp`

How can get only the formula ?

My OS is Linux Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. An option is add `linktoc = all, ...` to the variable org-latex-default-packages-alist => hyperref. You can do this via:

1. M-x customize-variable RET org-latex-default-packages-alist RET
2. Then go to the "option" field of package `hyperref` and write `linktoc = all, ...`
3. Finally hit the "Apply and Save" button and restart

This is a general approach, not for a single file. I test this procedure to hide the links (`hidelinks` option).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this happens when you have a `#+LATEX_HEADER: \hypersetup{...}` line in your org file. When org generates latex fragments, it generates a small latex file with the formula along with your full latex header. But it doesn't include all default packages in `org-latex-default-packages-alist`, only the ones with a `t`. And `hyperref` is one of the ones not included by default. Then I guess latex interprets the hypersetup contents as part of the document for some reason.

I found a few workarounds, in addition to the other answer here.

1. Remove the hypersetup line from your org file and set `org-latex-hyperref-template` in `~/.emacs.d/init.el` instead:

   `(setq org-latex-hyperref-template "\\hypersetup{linktoc=all,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue}")`

   (If you don't mind using the same options for all org files.)
2. Keep the hypersetup line in your org file, but add an explicit `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{hyperref}` line so it'll be loaded even when generating fragments.
3. Modify `org-latex-default-packages-alist` so that hyperref is marked with `t` and will be included when generating fragments.